# How to have a textview transition to the title in a collapsing toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` that contains a `TextView` and a `RatingBar` under the `TextView`. Would it be possible to have the `TextView` somehow transition to the title?

My current layout looks like this: [image]

I want "Title" to transition up as the toolbar collapses. There will also be a back button, so how would I ensure that the textview transitions to the proper place (to the right side of the back button)?

EDIT: Here is my XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_view_app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                fontPath="fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/large_text"/>

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout XML?  You can probably get what you want without using a separate TextView for the title.

Comment: @krislarson i added the xml.

Comment: I've been working on your solution but I don't have a working example yet.  The basic idea is that you don't need the TextView for the title; you would add a support Toolbar instead, then set the title on the CollapsingToolbarLayout.  The title will transition to the correct place as the toolbar collapses.  You can set the positioning on expanded title with the `android:expandedTitleMargin` parameters, so it's positioned above the rating bar.  Look at the detail activity in Chris Banes' cheesesquare demo to see this in action: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: how would i be able to position it so that the rating bar will be below the title?

Comment: You would use `app:expandedTitleMarginBottom` attribute on the CollapsingToolbarLayout. (It's not the android prefix like in my earlier comment.)  Make the margin large enough so that the title clears the rating bar.  You can position the expanded title pretty much anywhere you want, and when the toolbar collapses, the title goes right back to the usual place.

Comment: I added an answer to demonstrate what I was talking about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is: Don't use a `TextView`.

You can position the expanded title wherever you want by using these `CollapsingToolbarLayout` attributes:

```
app:expandedTitleGravity        default is bottom|left -or- bottom|start
app:expandedTitleMargin
app:expandedTitleMarginBottom
app:expandedTitleMarginStart
app:expandedTitleMarginEnd
```

I am assuming you are using a `NoActionBar` theme, which is why you started off with the `TextView` for the title.

So here is your layout, fixed up to use the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` title:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_view_app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <!-- 
                 set the expandedTitleMarginBottom to a value 
                 that positions the expanded title above the rating bar
              -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then in your code, set the title on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Title");
```

Comment: As you have mentioned - You can position the expanded title wherever you want by using these CollapsingToolbarLayout attributes. By using this title position changes but toolbar is present at that position only. So my rating bar click is not working as it hides under the toolbar(but not visible to us). How to solve this ?

Comment: @Raj it's hard to tell without seeing your code, but you probably want to have your rating bar inside a `ScrollView` or other scrolling view that is below the `AppBarLayout` but inside the `CoordinatorLayout`.  Please submit a new question with the relevant parts of your code and the SO community will be able to help you.  You can post a link to your question in a comment on this question and I will take a look at it.